# Maphilight and change src of a picture

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an Image with a map and a few areas in it. I want to highlight them when the the mouse is over it (using this lib http://davidlynch.org/projects/maphilight/docs/). This works fine with this js-code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){$('.map').maphilight();});
</script>
```

and this HTML code:

```
<div id="content">
    <img src="./media/torten.png" width="800" height="600" alt="" usemap="#tortendiagramm" class="map" id="bild">
</div>

        <map name="tortendiagramm">
            <area shape="poly" coords="410,280,410,55,500,75,590,145,630,240,630,330">
            <area shape="poly" coords="410,280,630,330,618,360">
            <area shape="poly" coords="410,280,618,360,580,425,510,480,400,504,305,477">
            <area shape="poly" coords="410,280,305,477,260,445">
            <area shape="poly" coords="410,280,260,445,220,400,200,350">
            <area shape="poly" coords="410,280,200,350,190,319">
            <area shape="poly" coords="410,280,190,319,190,243,210,178,234,144,282,96,335,70,410,55">
        </map>
```

Now I would like to change the whole Image (with fadeout/fadein) and delete the map when I click on a certain area using

```
            <area shape="poly" coords="410,280,410,55,500,75,590,145,630,240,630,330" onclick="changeImage('./media/1.png')">
```

with this js-code:

```
function changeImage(bild)
        {   
            alert('clicked');

            $('#bild').attr('usemap','');
            $('#bild').fadeOut('slow', function()
            {   
                $('#bild').attr('src', bild);
                $('#bild').fadeIn('slow');
            });
        }
```

The alert box pops up but the image do not change. 
If I delete the map highlight code then its changing the image with fadein/out.

Any ideas how I can change an image with highlight?

Comment: Did you try inspecting the page when you call the function and see what is it coming in console window?

Comment: Yes. I added a console.log("clicked")(when i click on the area) and console.log("ready") (at the end of the code) and nothing else shows in the console.